# How do I disable validation in a Silverlight 4 application?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, validation, wcf-ria-services

**update** How do I disable validation in a Silverlight 4 application?  It looks like this is something not unique to RIA Services (as my original question below implies).  I observe this when I bind my datagrid to a list of POCOs and I trigger a validation error in my grid (e.g. typing in a non-numeric in a cell bound to a numeric property).  How does one disable the validation in this instance? **end update**

How do I disable (turn off) validation in a grid that is bound to classes generated by RIA Services in my Silverlight application.  I would like to disable validation just for this grid; there are other controls where I would like to use validation.

e.g. Let's say I've got a RIA services generated class called Customer with the fields: ID, FirstName, LastName.  All the corresponding fields in my Customer table in the database are not nullable (thus, required).  A collection of the Customer classes are bound to a grid:

```
myGrid.itemsSource = myListOfCustomers
```

And for each column in my grid, I've defined a binding to one of the properties, e.g.

```
="{Binding FirstName}"
```

I'd like my user to be able to enter anything in any of the cells in my grid without the validation messages from appearing.  e.g. Right now, entering a non-numeric in my integer ID column results in a validation message being displayed.

I've got an application set up with RIA Services, Entity Framework 4, and Silverlight 4.  It is set up in the standard fashion prescribed on MSDN here: [Walkthrough: Creating a RIA Services Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707376%28v=VS.91%29.aspx)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Entering non-numeric in my Integer ID results in validation" ?  If you want your user to enter anything then make the column as Text, what is need for user to add anything if it is an integer column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but did you try to set the NotifyOnValidationError and related properties on the bindings to false?

Comment: I wonder what the record is for longest time between asked, answered, and accepted questions on stackoverflow.  For the benefit of others, here are all the binding properties that you can try setting to false: NotifyOnValidationError, ValidatesOnExceptions, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors